# XSL : follow and preceding don't work (Kayessian method)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

i cannot make preceding (or preceding-sibling) and following (or following-sibling) working correctly:

I have the following xml:

```
<doc xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xml:lang="it">
    <articolo id="U50779749147XPB">
        <testatina id="U50779749147xtG">
            <ln>in breve</ln>
        </testatina>
        <breve id="U50779749147yAC">
            <h1>melegnano</h1>
            <h2>Si ribalta</h2>
            <h2>con l’auto</h2>
            <h2>alla rotonda</h2>
            <p>
                <span class="rettangolo">n</span>
                Sempre caro mi fu quest'ermo colle, e questa siepe, che da tanta
                parte dell'ultimo orizzonte il guardo esclude. Ma sedendo e mirando,
            </p>
            <p class="rimando">
                segue a pagina
                <span class="pagina">5</span>
            </p>
            <h1>castelnuovo</h1>
            <h2>Protesta</h2>
            <h2>delle mamme</h2>
            <h2>per la scuola</h2>
            <p>
                <span class="rettangolo">n</span>
                Sempre caro mi fu quest'ermo colle, e questa siepe, che da tanta
                parte dell'ultimo orizzonte il guardo esclude. Ma sedendo e mirando
        </p>
            <p class="rimando">
                segue a pagina
                <span class="pagina">8</span>
            </p>
            <h1>salerano</h1>
            <h2>sull’incendio: </h2>
            <h2>«non ci sono </h2>
            <h2>misteri»</h2>
            <p>
                <span class="rettangolo">n</span>
                Sete il guardo esclude. Ma sedendo e mirando, interminati spazi di
            </p>
            <p class="rimando">
                segue a pagina
                <span class="pagina">6</span>
            </p>
        </breve>
    </articolo>
</doc>
```

I need to select all the nodes and content between the second and the third h1:
So basically:

```
            <h2>Protesta</h2>
            <h2>delle mamme</h2>
            <h2>per la scuola</h2>
            <p>
                <span class="rettangolo">n</span>
                Sempre caro mi fu quest'ermo colle, e questa siepe, che da tanta
                parte dell'ultimo orizzonte il guardo esclude. Ma sedendo e mirando
            </p>
            <p class="rimando">
                segue a pagina
                <span class="pagina">8</span>
            </p>
```

I tried everything but following and preceding are not working as expected:i tried

```
 <xsl:variable name="set" select="/doc/articolo/breve/h1[2]/following::node()[count(.|/doc/articolo/breve/h1[3]/preceding::node())=count(/doc/articolo/breve/h1[3]/preceding::node())]"/>
```

But the result is just the first h2: "Protesta" and it skips all the left h2 and p

So i tried to check the single result of operator following and preceding but the just return a few elements instead of everything preceding or following my node:
For example:

```
 <xsl:variable name="vtextPostM" select="following-sibling::doc/articolo/breve/h1[2]"/>
             <xsl:variable name="vtextPreN" select="preceding-sibling::doc/articolo/breve/h1[3]"/>
```

Is returnin no elements, this

```
<xsl:variable name="vtextPostM" select="/doc/articolo[1]/breve/h1[2]/following-sibling::node()"/>
             <xsl:variable name="vtextPreN" select="/doc/articolo[1]/breve/h1[3]/preceding-sibling::node()"/>
```

This ir returning a partial wrong set: following prints Protesta (and not all the other following node) and preceding Melegnano (the is h1[1] but what about all the node in the Middle). I did many other test but nothin, can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is again one of those things that would be trivial with XSLT2.0 and `<xsl:for-each-group>`, but since it looks like you're using XSLT1.0, here's one option:

#### Stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc/articolo/breve"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="breve">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="h1[2]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h1">
    <!--
    Apply following siblings whose first preceding <h1> sibling is the <h1>
    element currently being processed
    -->
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="following-sibling::*[not(self::h1)][preceding-sibling::h1[1]
        [generate-id() = generate-id(current())]]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breve>
  <h2>Protesta</h2>
  <h2>delle mamme</h2>
  <h2>per la scuola</h2>
  <p><span class="rettangolo">n</span>
                Sempre caro mi fu quest'ermo colle, e questa siepe, che da tanta
                parte dell'ultimo orizzonte il guardo esclude. Ma sedendo e mirando
        </p>
  <p class="rimando">
                segue a pagina
                <span class="pagina">8</span>
            </p>
</breve>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :) Do you know why mu use of followin and preceding was not correct?

Comment: It's difficult to be specific without seeing your entire stylesheet. You might find the "preceding-sibling and following-sibling" section of the [Axis Powers](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/12/20/xpathaxes.html#u85-8-1-3) article enlightening, in any case.